# Modifying strings in a list efficiently

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list of strings $\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\}$. I would like to to produce the following list of strings:
$$
\{s_1<>1,\ 1<>s_2<>1,\ldots,\ 1<>s_n\}
$$
In other words, I want to append the character $1$ to the end of the first string, to either end of all internal strings, and to the beginning of the final string. What is an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: If efficiency paramount, check my answer, and note that the `Riffle` based solution will break if strings contain spaces, unless you use a dummy character - which cannot exist in any string - possibly slowing further...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Flatten[
 {#[[1]] <> "1", StringInsert[#[[2 ;; -2]], "1", {1, -1}], 
  "1" <> #[[-1]]}] &@strings
```

About **2X** to over **10X** as fast (depending on string lengths) as `Riffle` et al. that I noted in comment, and unlike that this will return correct results if strings contain spaces. About 4X as fast as mapping (all tested on MMA 9).

Comment: That's the way go to IMO.

Comment: Nice. Can't believe it's that much faster though. Crazy. (+1)

Answer (score 13):

Here's a way with v10.1:

```
strings = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};

StringSplit@StringRiffle[strings, "1 1"]
```

> `{"a1", "1b1", "1c1", "1d1", "1e"}`

And if you're not on 10.1 (and as suggested by @ciao), you can achieve the same thing with:

```
StringSplit@StringJoin@Riffle[strings, "1 1"]
```

And just for the heck of it with `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexed[If[First@#2 == 1, "", "1"] <> #1 <> 
 If[First@#2 == Length@strings, "", "1"] &, strings]
```

Comment: +1 - and a similar construct (I won't post since it's the same in essence) for pre 10.x of `StringSplit@StringJoin[Riffle[s, "1 1"]]` is considerably faster than mapping solutions....

Answer (score 5):

Pedestrianly,

```
x = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

Flatten[{StringJoin[#, "1"] &@First[x],
  StringJoin["1", #, "1"] & /@ x[[2 ;; -2]],
  StringJoin["1", #] &@Last[x]}]
```

> {"a1", "1b1", "1c1", "1d"}

Comment: Hehe, learned a new adverb just now 

Comment: Like 'prosaic'.  (Prose, but not poetry.)